# elasticsearch won't work when using uppercase letters in query

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, laravel-4, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using laravel 4.2. my database is mongodb. I have a table called products and a  field in my db which is called `brand` that has a value of `ABC` in uppercase.

When using this query `['term' => ['brand' => 'ABC']]` the result set is empty.

But when i tried using this `['term' => ['brand' => 'abc']]` it is actually working and returning all the products with `brand = 'ABC'`.

My question is why elasticsearch cannot find uppercase letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your `brand` field is analyzed and thus `ABC` gets tokenized and indexed as `abc`, hence why a search for the `term` `abc` returns hits while `ABC` doesn't.

In order to change this behavior you may create a sub-field for your `brand` field that is `not_analyzed` and you'll be able to search for the uppercase form as well.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_mapping -d '{
    "properties": {
        "brand": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

If you run the command above and re-index your data, you'll then be able to search for

```
['term' => ['brand.raw' => 'ABC']]
```

Note that you may also use `match` queries (see below) on your `brand` field and they'll return matches.

```
['match' => ['brand' => 'abc']]
['match' => ['brand' => 'ABC']]
```

Comment: this is a great explanation. Thank you. now I know it is indexed as lowercase.

Comment: I am new to elasticsearch and still learning it. I still have few more questions to post.

Comment: Feel free to post them ;-)